# Label not showing at runtime at the same place it is in storyboard

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, storyboard, label

I created an PNG for the background and used with an Image View. The image has a sentence which is: 'Relação Risco/Ganho:'and is followed by the result that will be shown up through a Label. The Label was positioned at the same baseline as the text in the image.

When I ran the app it was working fine yesterday, but today all of a sudden the Label does not appear at the same position it is in storyboard.

Below are the the screenshots.

[image: Image from the Storyboard file]

[image: Image from the iPad Simulator]

So anyone have an idea what is causing this??

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your autoresize options are set correctly.

[image]

Comment: Yes they are!! They are just like your image.

Comment: That is the issue then, remove the top "I".

Comment: Well, all is back working again, but I had to create a new project and do it all again. Thanks for those who helped!!!